# Pod stopped working with error the resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I deployed pod in OpenShift cluster, it stops processing PVC's after some time and it is giving following statements in log:

```
watch of *v1.PersistentVolume ended with:The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
watch of *v1.StorageClass ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
watch of *v1.PersistentVolumeClaim ended with: The resourceVersion for the provided watch is too old.
```

I wanted to know in which case above error occures and how to handle it.

Comment: Where is your OpenShit cluster running? Where are your volumes? Can you add more details? Thx.

Comment: What level(info, error, warn ...) are the above messages ? I thinks the messages are just information for notice requirement against old revision results through the above API, so other same API requests will send to API server for getting results with the recent revision.

Comment: messaged are of warn level . pod stops working suddenly and i checked the logs then found above statements. if these are warning messages then why it is stopping the pod , and after restarting the pod it is working. but i dont want to restart the pod eveytime.

Comment: Rico , Openshift cluster is running on instances created on vmware and volumes are at storage provider's storageproduct. Here we are trying to use dynamic volume provisioning concept of kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

It's informational as suggested in your question's comments:

> The warning is issued as a result of watch being restarted, which happens when etcd drops the connection and we relist the resources. This warning is not fatal
>   and informs the user that the watchers are operating properly. If customer won't see this warning in logs, that will be somewhat concerning and might suggest that their watches/cache
>   is not healthy.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1573460